# PagingLibrary with recyclerView can not stop loadAfter()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging

loadAfter() can't stop even though I didn't swipe the RecyclerView.
It keeps calling onBindView->loadAfter()

I tried to debug, find these:
method **loadAroundInternal** in class **ContiguousPagedList**

```
int appendItems = getAppendItemsRequested(mConfig.prefetchDistance, index, mStorage.getLeadingNullCount() + mStorage.getStorageCount());
```

**index** keep ++ while **getBindView** in recyclerView is being bigger
the **appendItem** is always >0

I'm not sure, but I think maybe

```
network->appendPage->notifyInserted->bindView->loadAfter->network
```

then the recyclerView adapter execute onBindView.But the bindViewHolder which position should't call called. So it can't stop.

I don't know whether I'm right or not.And I don't know how to fix it.

below are some relevant code I wrote：

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    VB binding = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(holder.itemView);
    setData(binding, getItem(position));
    binding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

In my own **PagingDataSource** which extends **PageKeyedDataSource**

```
@Override
public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, T> callback) {
    singleCreator.createSingle(params.key, params.requestedLoadSize)
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Page<T>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Page<T> tPage) {
                    callback.onResult(tPage.list, tPage.pageNumber + 1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            });

}

public interface SingleCreator<T> {
    SingleSubscribeProxy<Page<T>> createSingle(int page, int pageSize);
}
```

If other things need, I will edit the question

=====================================

Add message：I found if I set an absolute value for recyclerView's height, such as 100dp, It works fine. Butwork with problem when wrap_content and match_parent.

So the problem now is:when 2 recyclerViews in nestedScrollView and with a wrap_content or match_parent, the bindView can't stop loadAfter() which is a method of paging library.

Answer (score 3):

So the reason why It happened 
When a network result backs, the recycleView refresh.
Since it's in a nestedScrollView, it has no exact height.
Then onSizeChanged->getItem->network.

For me, the solution is
write a custom linearLayout which implements **NestedScrollingParent2**;